# Como comprobar si una clave esta en un diccionario en javascript

Tags: javascript, diccionarios

Tengo el siguiente diccionario:

```
diccionario = {1: "uno", 2: "dos", 3: "tres"}
```

Me gustaría ver si contiene una clave determinada, por ejemplo, el 2.
¿Cómo puedo saberlo?

Y ya de paso...me gustaría saber también como comprobar si un valor se encuentra en el diccionario. ¿Cómo se le da un valor y se te devuelve una clave?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El concepto de diccionario aquí es ambiguo:

### Objetos como diccionarios (o Hash Maps)

Lo que tú llamas diccionario es un objeto básico en Javascript.

Para obtener las claves tienes esta funcionalidad:

```js
let diccionario = {1: "uno", 2: "dos", 3: "tres"};

let claves=Object.keys(diccionario);

console.log(claves);
```

Por otro lado, podrías recorrer las claves de la siguiente manera:

```js
let diccionario = {1: "uno", 2: "dos", 3: "tres"};

for (let i in diccionario) {
  console.log('la clave es',i);
}
```

Pero para saber si una clave existe, de manera *pragmática*, puedes simplemente comparar con `undefined`:

```js
let diccionario = {1: "uno", 2: "dos", 3: "tres"};

for (let i=0;i<5;i++) {
  if (diccionario[i] === undefined) {
    console.log('la clave',i,'no está presente');
  } else {
    console.log('la clave',i,'está presente');
  }
}
```

Si bien es cierto que la clave puede estar presente, pero no guardar ningún valor, en la práctica no hay diferencia entre considerar que no está presente o que su valor es undefined:

```js
let objeto={ a: 1, b: undefined, c: 3};

console.log(Object.keys(objeto));

console.log('Miramos b:', objeto.b);
console.log('Miramos d:', objeto.d);

delete objeto.a;

console.log('Hemos quitado a, las claves restantes son',Object.keys(objeto));
console.log('comprobamos su valor:', objeto.a);
```

Si quieres saber si **realmente** la clave no existe, ni siquiera con valor undefined, existe el método `hasOwnProperty`:

```js
let obj = {1: "uno", 2: undefined, 3: "tres"};

console.log("existe 1?", obj.hasOwnProperty(1));
console.log("existe 2?", obj.hasOwnProperty(2)); //aunque sea undefined
```

### Diccionario *real* (usando una clase diseñada para tal fin)

Di lo que quieres realmente es un diccionario, Javascript tiene la clase [**Map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Map), que da más posibilidades que un simple objeto, como que las claves puedan ser objetos y no meramente texto o números, o que puedas preguntar cuantos elementos hay:

```js
var miMapa = new Map();

//Potenciales claves
var claveObj = {},
    claveFunc = function () {},
    claveCadena = "una cadena";

// asignando valores
miMapa.set(claveCadena, "valor asociado con 'una cadena'");
miMapa.set(claveObj, "valor asociado con claveObj");
miMapa.set(claveFunc, "valor asociado with claveFunc");

console.log("Tamaño",miMapa.size);
console.log("buscando con una clave string",miMapa.get(claveCadena));    
console.log("buscando con una clave objeto",miMapa.get(claveObj));
console.log("buscando con una clave función",miMapa.get(claveFunc));

console.log('Existe "una cadena" como clave?',miMapa.has("una cadena"));
```

Comment: En la parte de si una clave existe creo que cambiaría el código, ya que lo que esas haciendo si bien cumple su función no es lo más correcto, ya que estas usando un 5 a pelo y un valor puede contener varias claves.

Comment: @AnonimoPer Simplemente estoy eligiendo como ejemplo 5 posibles claves, de las cuales algunas existen y otras no.

Answer (score 2):

Para saber que tu diccionario tiene una clave especifica puedes utilizar este código:

```
Object.keys(diccionario).includes("2")
```

Con Object.keys(diccionario) obtienes todas las claves del objeto diccionario y con la función includes buscas si existe un valor "2" en la lista de claves.

Bueno para obtener las claves para un valor en concreto te valdría esto:

```
var valor = "tres";
diccionario = {1: "uno", 2: "dos", 3: "tres", "prueba": "tres"}
var clavesPorValor = [];
Object.keys(diccionario).forEach( propiedad => { 
         if (diccionario[propiedad] === valor) { 
               clavesPorValor.push(propiedad);
         }
})
console.log(clavesPorValor);
```

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Para saber si contiene una llave, podrias utilizar `.hasOwnProperty()`:

```js
var diccionario = {1: "uno", 2: "dos", 3: "tres"};
console.log(diccionario.hasOwnProperty("0"));
console.log(diccionario.hasOwnProperty("1"));
```

Para saber si contiene un valor, podrias utilizar los metodos de `Object`:

- `Object.values()` retorna los valores enumerables del objeto, en el mismo orden que se verian en un `for in`
- `Object.keys()` retorna las llaves enumerables del objeto, en el mismo orden que se verian en un `for in`

```js
var diccionario = {
  1: "uno",
  2: "dos",
  3: "tres"
};

llaveParaValor(diccionario, "uno");
llaveParaValor(diccionario, "cinco");


function llaveParaValor(o, val) {
  var i = Object.values(o).indexOf(val);
  if (i >= 0) {
    console.log(Object.keys(o)[i]);
  } else {
    console.log("no existe el valor");
  }
}
```

Comment: La función llaveParaValor me parece que solo devuelve la primera llave para un valor, pero que ocurre si ese valor se encuentra en dos llaves? Por ello creo que es mejor devolver un array de llaves para el valor. Saludos.

Comment: @anonimoper es una buena idea, pero depende de lo que quiera hacer el OP. El en particular solo menciona obtener la clave

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la mejor forma de realizar la verificación de la llave es la siguiente:

```
diccionario.hasOwnProperty(llave); //Retorna valor booleano.
```

Todo objeto descendiente de Object hereda el método hasOwnProperty. Este método puede ser usando para determinar si un objeto tiene la propiedad especificada como una propiedad directa de ese objeto; a diferencia del operador `in`, este método no verifica la cadena prototipo del objeto.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener las llaves:

```
Object.keys(objeto)
```

Para obtener los valores:

```
Object.values(objeto)
```

Para darle valor a una clave:

```
objeto["clave"] = nuevo_valor;
```

Comment: muy útil la sentencia Object.values(objeto), lo único que vale a partir de la versión 54 de chrome, yo tengo la 49 : (