# Cómo buscar una llave en un array de varias dimensiones

Tags: array, filtro

Hola a todos y gracias por la ayuda, mi problema es que necesito sacar una llave de un array de 2 dimensiones puede ser el Id. He leído acerca del método filter pero no encuentro la manera apropiada de hacerlo, estoy trabajando con Angular. Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega la información sobre el lenguaje de programación que estás utilizando así como tu código para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Si lo que quieres es simplemente ver si una clave existe puedes usar el bucle for y complobar si existe o no: ´function exist_key(arr,key){for (let i in arr){ if (key===i && key==i){return true;} } return false; }´. pero si lo que quieres es obtener todos los keys y no tener que usar for puedes usar el metodo keys de la clase Object: ´Object.keys(arr);´. Nota: arr es tu array. - Recomiendo que mejores la pregunta(porque no estoy seguro de lo que quieres) y visites los enlaces que da @HeytalePazguato , EDICIÓN: Me equivoque un poco con el codigo. ( :

Comment: Lectura adicional: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/159121/como-comprobar-si-una-clave-esta-en-un-diccionario-en-javascript

Comment: @DanielBriceño cual es el punto de comparar con `==` luego de comparar con `===`? No es redundante?

Comment: @Fedex7501 Era para optimizar la función, pero veo que JavaScript trata los índices como cadena no tiene ninguna utilidad: var arr={1:"hola","hola":"como estas"};console.log(arr["1"]);. recuerda que === es para comparar el tipo de dato y JavaScript ve 1=="1", cuando "1" es una cadena y 1 es un entero.